# How do I delete "Removable Disk" listings?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I've recently had some "Removable Disk" listings mysteriously appear along with my other drives. Clicking on one of them results in a dialog box:

> Please insert a disk into Removable Disk (G:). "Properties" has no usable data.

How do I delete these "Removable Disk" listings?

```
Computer
Local Disk (C:)
Data2 (D:)
DVR (E:)
BD-ROM Drive (F:) DVD
Removable Disk (G:)
Removable Disk (H:)
Removable Disk (I:)
Removable Disk (J:)
Maxtor .5GB Set 2 LR Sec (K:)
LR3 Set3 Pri Seagate2TB (L:)
Grn Mxtr .5GB Bkup of Mxtr .5GB (M:)
Maxtor .5GB Set 2 LR Primary (N:)
Removable Disk (O:)
```

Answer (score 5):

If some of those drives are for things like camera memory card readers, then this is typically how they work.

To hide empty drive letters from the list, use the following menu options in Windows Explorer:

1. "Tools" menu
2. "Folder options" item
3. "View" tab
4. Enable the "Hide empty drives in the Computer folder" checkbox
5. "OK" button

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are two settings that control whether you can see the empty drives.

1. 'Hide empty drives in the Computer folder'
2. 'Hidden files and folders'.

If `Show hidden files, folders, and drives` is selected (the default is `Don't show`) then you will still see the hidden removable drives even if `Hide empty drives in the Computer folder` is ticked.

To hide the drives completely you need to:

1. Click the `Start` button.
2. Type `Folder Options` and press `Enter`.
3. Select the `View` tab.
4. Select `Don't show hidden files, folders, or drives`.
5. Tick `Hide empty drives in the Computer folder`.
6. Click `OK`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These sound like they may be from a media/memory card reader. You can set to hide empty drives to remove/hide them until you insert a memory card. Use the link: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/6969-drives-hide-show-empty-drives-computer-folder.html to learn how.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Welcome to Super User! [It would be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link only for future reference.